# MySQL Before update trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have current trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER ChangeAutoIncrementMeasures ON Measures 
 FOR EACH ROW BEFORE INSERT
 BEGIN 
  SET @@auto_increment_increment = 100
 END;
```

But i get 1064 Error. Where is my mistake ?

Edit: It should be :

```
CREATE TRIGGER ChangeAutoIncrementVendors BEFORE INSERT ON Vendors 
FOR EACH ROW 
    SET @@auto_increment_increment = 10
```

Comment: Error 1064 is a syntax error. Post and analyze the whole error code please

Comment: needs semicolon after the SET statement, I would imagine...

Comment: @PaulDixon +1 correct. that's the syntax error causing the 1064

Comment: I found the mistake it was really a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Need an semicolon after your SET statement, and the BEFORE INSERT moving....

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER ChangeAutoIncrementMeasures BEFORE INSERT ON Measures 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  SET @@auto_increment_increment = 100;
END;
//

delimiter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the syntax as follows

```
CREATE TRIGGER ChangeAutoIncrementMeasures

BEFORE INSERT ON Measures 

FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  SET @@auto_increment = 100;
 END
```